# consecutive adding and substracting double values

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy, double-precision

Given double values:

```
double a
double b
b < a
```

if:

```
double c = a - b;
double d = c + b
```

then does double number guarantee that:

```
d == a ?
```

Example:

```
double c = 20.0d - 2.0d;
double d = c + 2.0d;
```

is it true that d will be again equal to 20.0d?
So in general I am asking if I substract and add the same double would it be still the 
same value ?
This is only one case where a=20.0d and b= 2.0d.
I need to be sure for this for every double value.

I tried with such example:

```
double s = 4.8d;
System.out.print(s + "\n");
s -= 0.4d;
System.out.print(s + "\n");
s += 0.4d;
System.out.print(s + "\n");
```

For this example the result matched my expectations:

```
4.8
4.3999999999999995
4.8
```

So this is what I need.

Thanks.

Comment: If, rather than `b < a`, you know that `a/2 < b < 2a`, then the property you are asking about holds. This is Sterbenz's lemma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this will work for 20 and 2, it is definitely not going to work in general: it will break for double values when the addition forces an increment of the exponent portion of the representation: the result will lose some precision.

Here is a simple example (in Java) illustrating the point:

```
double a = 1.0 / 3;
double b = 0.5;
double c = a + b;
double d = c - b;
System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(d);
System.out.println(a == d);
```

[When you run it, this example prints the following](http://ideone.com/CKk3Ia):

```
0.3333333333333333
0.33333333333333326
false
```

The results become even more pronounced when the exponents of the values being added are different. For example, if you change `b`'s value from `0.5` to `100000`, the [difference would be a lot bigger](http://ideone.com/LX9yq6):

```
0.3333333333333333
0.3333333333284827
false
```

Changing `b` to `1E15` gives

```
0.3333333333333333
0.375
false
```

Changing `b` to `1E20` makes even the traces of the original `a` disappear:

```
0.3333333333333333
0.0
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. For example:

```
> a=1.1; b=10; (a-b) + b
1.0999999999999996
```

Comment: This example does not satisfy the `b < a` pre-condition in the question (although examples exist that do, of course).